# capture output of runas command cross domain

Tags: runas, sysinternals

I want to run the sysinternals tool psloglist to get the event log of a server that is on another domain.

If I run

```
runas /netonly /user:DOMAIN2\USER psloglist \\TARGETSERVER
```

Then a new command window appears and the I see the correct data being listed.

How can I capture this output in a file on my machine on DOMAIN1?

I tried

```
runas /netonly /user:DOMAIN2\USER psloglist \\TARGETSERVER > event.log
```

Which captured the runas password prompt.

I also tried creating a batch file with

```
psloglist \\TARGETSERVER > event.log
```

and running

```
runas /netonly /user:DOMAIN2\USER mybatchfile
```

but that instantly returns and no command window appears and no file is created.

I presume this is because DOMAIN2\USER cannot create the event.log file on my machine, how can I get around this?

DOMAIN1 has no trust with DOMAIN2 and I cannot added it.

Answer (score 0):

Well you have two options you can either use:

runas /savecred /domain2\user xxxx xxxxx

Then enter password so it 'saves' the credentials, then run again to get output...

runas /savecred /domain2\user xxxx xxxxx > output.log

Or you use a VBS script which has the password stored as plain text within.. If this would work for you let me know and I'll knock something up however plain text passwords never a good idea...

Comment: runas will not let me use /savecred  and /netuse at the same time and I can not see how to avoid using both

Comment: very true... yep runas is no good for you.. are happy with a script that contains the password?

Comment: yes this is just an internal monitoring tool

Answer (score 0):

Seems I missed a trick, even though all the examples for psloglist show the argument -u with just a user name it does work with a domain.

So my working solution is

```
psloglist \\TARGETSERVER -u DOMAIN2\USER -p PASSWORD > event.log
```

Note the password has to be supplied otherwise the prompt gets swallowed by the redirection.